# Intersection between nested lists java 8 streams

Tags: java, java-8, nested, java-stream

I have a nested list of `Long`. for example:

```
List<List<Long>> ids = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3,4],[2,3]];
```

Is there a way using streams to create a new list of items that are present in all the lists:

```
List<Long> result = [2,3];
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is quite concise solution without stream:

```
List<Long> result = new ArrayList<>(ids.get(0));
ids.forEach(result::retainAll);

System.out.println(result);
```

**Update**: as it was mentioned in the comments by @ernest_k to avoid the superfluous `retainAll()` call you can get sublist before:

```
ids.subList(1, ids.size()).forEach(result::retainAll);
```

Comment: `ids.subList(1, ids.size()).forEach(result::retainAll);` will improve this by avoiding the superfluous `ids.get(0).retainAll(ids.get(0))` call

Answer (score 4):

Here's a (less concise) `Stream` version using `reduce`:

```
List<Long> intersect = ids.stream()
                          .reduce(ids.get(0),
                                  (l1,l2) -> {
                                      l1.retainAll(l2);
                                      return l1;
                                  });
```

Or (if we want to avoid mutating the original `List`s):

```
List<Long> intersect = ids.stream()
                          .reduce(new ArrayList<>(ids.get(0)),
                                  (l1,l2) -> {
                                      l1.retainAll(l2);
                                      return l1;
                                  });
```